# How to run macOS build with catalyst on Github Actions?

Tags: swift, xcode, continuous-integration, github-actions, swift-package-manager

Does Github Actions support running my build on catalyst?

```
name: Swift

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
 build:

runs-on: macos-latest

steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
- name: Build
  run: swift build -v
- name: Run tests
  run: swift test -v
```

If so how can i add that configuration to the above Actions script?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this [swift starter](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/blob/master/ci/swift.yml), in your attached script, I can see some yaml indentation issue, it would be good that you can post your repo for further discussion.

```yaml
name: Swift

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: macos-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Build
      run: swift build -v
    - name: Run tests
      run: swift test -v
```